# JQuery UI Dialog Ajax PHP not working on second submit

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a standard setup.  I have a php page that serves up data.  Within the data are some edit links.  My issue is that after I edit some data, the second time I click on an edit link, my JQuery-UI opens up on the url passed to it instead of populating the JQuery-UI.dialog.

**Base Page Java (view.php)**

```
   var editParyAddress = $('#edit_party_address').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width:'auto',
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        'Save': function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: '/party_address/save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#edit_party_address_form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
              $.get('helper.php?function=partyaddress&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>',function(data){$('#partyaddress').html(data);});
              //$('#edit_party_address').dialog('close');
              $('#edit_party_address').dialog("destroy").remove();
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });

    $('.edit_party_address').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
          editParyAddress.html(data);
          editParyAddress.dialog('open');
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
```

**PHP Page that feeds the data to the JQuery-UI.dailog (edit.php)**

```
$sql="SELECT dbo.format_full_name(p.first_name,p.middle_name,p.last_name) name, dp.party_id, pa.id partyaddressid, pa.address1,pa.address2,pa.city,pa.state,pa.zip_code,pa.address_indicator_id,pa.is_active
FROM [".DB1."].[DBO].[party_address] pa
INNER JOIN debt_party dp on dp.party_id=pa.party_id
INNER JOIN party p on p.id=pa.party_id
where pa.id=".$_GET['party_address_id'];
$HTML='';
$conn =db_connect();
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql,array(),array( "Scrollable" => 'keyset' ));
if( $stmt === false) { error($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);return;}

$HTML= '<form name="edit_party_address_form" id="edit_party_address_form" style="width:100%" action="">';
if ($stmt===false) {return;}
if (sqlsrv_has_rows( $stmt )=== false){return;}
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$HTML.='<fieldset>';
$HTML.='<ol>';
$HTML.='<li><label for="address_address1">Address 1:</label><input class="text-input" id="address1" name="address1" size="30" type="text" value="'.$row['address1'].'"></li>';
$HTML.='<li><label for="address_address2">Address 2:</label><input class="text-input" id="address2" name="address2" size="30" type="text" value="'.$row['address2'].'"></li>';
$HTML.='<li><label for="address_city">City:</label><input class="address" id="address_city" name="address_city" size="30" type="text" value="'.$row['city'].'"></li>';
$HTML.='<li><label for="address_state">State:</label><input class="state" id="address_state" name="address_state" maxlength="2" size="2" type="text" value="'.$row['state'].'"></li>';
$HTML.='<li><label for="address_zip_code">Zip Code:</label><input class="zip_code" id="address_zip_code" maxlength="10" name="address_zip_code" size="10" type="text" value="'.$row['zip_code'].'"></li>';
$HTML.='<li><label for="name">Indicator:</label>'.HTMLOptions(DB1,'dbo','address_indicator','id','name',$row['address_indicator_id']).'</li>';
$HTML.='<li><label for="is_active">Active:</label><input '.($row['is_active']==1? ' checked="checked"':'').' name="is_active" maxlength="2" size="2" type="checkbox" value="'.$row['is_active'].'"></li>';
$HTML.='<li><input id="party_address_id" name="party_address_id" type="hidden" value="'.$_GET['party_address_id'].'"></li>';
$HTML.='</ol>';

$HTML.='</fieldset>';
$HTML.='</form>';
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
echo $HTML;
```

**PHP Save page (save.php)**

```
$sql="UPDATE party_address SET address1='".$_POST['address1']."',address2='".$_POST['address2']."'  WHERE id=".$_POST['party_address_id'];   

    $conn =db_connect();
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql,array(),array( "Scrollable" => 'keyset' ));
    if( $stmt === false) { error($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);return;}
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```

When I click an edit link which looks like this: `/party_address/edit.php?party_address_id=1468941` it all works perfectly.  Once I submit the posted form changes, it updates the database and the view.php base page just fine.  After I submit a change, the second time I click on any edit link, the link utilizes the default behavior and the browsers address is changed to the edit link.  This just shows the inner HTML of my view.php page.  It should open up in the JQuery-UI.dialog `<div id="edit_party_address" title="Edit Party Address"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed two lines in my 
**Base Page Java (view.php)**
For clarity I just left them commented here.  Now it works!!!

```
var editParyAddress = $('#edit_party_address').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,  width:'auto',  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    'Save': function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/party_address/save.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#edit_party_address_form').serialize(),

        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
          $.get('helper.php?function=partyaddress&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>',function(data){$('#partyaddress').html(data);});
          $('#edit_party_address').dialog('close');
          //$('#edit_party_address').dialog("destroy").remove();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
// $('.edit_party_address').click(function(e){
$(document).on('click', '.edit_party_address', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
      editParyAddress.html(data);
      editParyAddress.dialog('open');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```